# Nativescript ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js

Tags: angular, firebase, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Im working on an App with Nativescript Angular and code sharing. After upgrading to Angular 10 a few days ago all worked fine. Today I wanted to implement Firebase with the plugin [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) but as I try to run my app I get the following Error:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/application/application'

ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/messaging/messaging.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/application/application'

ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/admob/admob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/platform/platform'

ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/messaging/messaging.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/platform/platform'
```

I assume it is thrown by Webpack because it is logged during webpack compiling.
My package.json looks somewhat like this:

```
 {
  "name": "application-name",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "my.nativescript.app",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.2"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.3"
    }
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    // some scripts
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~10.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "rc",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.5.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@nativescript/tslint-rules": "~0.0.5",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^6.5.15",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Just to understand the error I tried changing the import in the mentioned files to `tns-core-modules/application` and so on. The compiling worked but the app crashed as soon as I started it on my Simulator. I also tried `@nativescript/core/application/application`. I got the same Error.

I don't have any clue how to fix this problem so I would appreciate every help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.0.0-rc.0".
import * as firebase from @nativescript/firebase

check this link:
https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-compatible-plugins/